# How to filter the result of an INNER JOIN with a MAX function

Tags: sql, postgresql, inner-join

I need to add a filter with MAX function to the result of this query;

```
SELECT a.INTEGER_0, a.INTEGER_1, a.DATE_0, a.DATE_1, a.INTEGER_2
FROM TABLE_A a           
INNER JOIN               
   (SELECT b.INTEGER_0, b.INTEGER_1, b.DATE_0, max(b.DATE_1) AS max_date
    FROM TABLE_A b     
    GROUP BY b.INTEGER_0, b.INTEGER_1, b.DATE_0
   ) AS result         
ON  a.INTEGER_0 = b.INTEGER_0
AND a.INTEGER_1 = b.INTEGER_1
AND a.DATE_0 = b.DATE_0  
AND a.DATE_1 = b.max_date
```

This is ok!! But I need to filter the result whit `max(INTEGER_2)`.
I tried with another INNER JOIN but the result is bad!

**Additional info**
Rows:

```
1,7,'2011-02-01','2011-01-01',8
1,7,'2011-02-01','2011-01-02',7
1,7,'2011-02-01','2011-01-04',6
1,7,'2011-02-01','2011-01-04',3
1,7,'2011-02-01','2011-01-04',3
```

Correct result:

```
1,7,'2011-02-01','2011-01-04',6
```

Comment: Define a "bad" result?  Can you give sample data and expected output?

Comment: Many many rows :P i need filter from result with max(b.INTEGER_2), because if i add max(b.INTEGER_2) as max_int_2 and add to ON -> AND a.INTEGER_2 = b.max_int_2 i lost some rows with b.max_date because the column INTEGER_2 in some case contain bad data... thx for answer!

Answer (score 1):

First off, you have a **syntax error in your query**: the alias of the subquery is `AS result`. You confuse that with the inner alias of `b`.

#### 1 row

If you want just **one** row with `max(integer_2)` then `ORDER BY` / `LIMIT` will do the job. Your query could look like this:

```
SELECT a.integer_0, a.integer_1, a.date_0, a.date_1, a.integer_2
FROM   table_a a           
JOIN   (
    SELECT b.integer_0, b.integer_1, b.date_0, max(b.date_1) as max_date
    FROM   table_a b     
    GROUP  BY b.integer_0, b.integer_1, b.date_0
    ) AS b ON a.integer_0 = b.integer_0
        AND a.integer_1 = b.integer_1
        AND a.date_0 = b.date_0  
        AND a.date_1 = b.max_date
ORDER  BY a.integer_2 DESC
LIMIT  1;
```

#### All rows

If you want **all** rows of your result set with `max(integer_2)` (as your query deems to imply) then you could do this:

```
SELECT a.integer_0, a.integer_1, a.date_0, a.date_1, a.integer_2
FROM   table_a a           
JOIN   (
    SELECT b.integer_0, b.integer_1, b.date_0, max(b.date_1) as max_date
    FROM   table_a b     
    GROUP  BY b.integer_0, b.integer_1, b.date_0
    ) AS b ON a.integer_0 = b.integer_0
        AND a.integer_1 = b.integer_1
        AND a.date_0 = b.date_0  
        AND a.date_1 = b.max_date
WHERE (a.date_1, a.integer_2) = (
        SELECT date_1, integer_2
        FROM   table_a
        ORDER  BY 1 DESC, 2 DESC
        LIMIT  1);
```

### Or better yet, greatly simplify to:

```
SELECT integer_0, integer_1, date_0, date_1, integer_2
FROM   table_a a           
WHERE     (integer_0, integer_1, date_0, date_1, integer_2) = ( 
    SELECT integer_0, integer_1, date_0, date_1, integer_2
    FROM   table_a b
    ORDER  BY 4 DESC, 5 DESC
    LIMIT  1);
-- ORDER  BY something?  -- add these lines ..
-- LIMIT  1;            -- .. if you want just one row
```

#### Or simplify some more

```
SELECT *
FROM   table_a a           
WHERE  (a) = ( 
    SELECT b
    FROM   table_a b
    ORDER  BY date_1 DESC, integer_2 DESC
    LIMIT  1);
-- ORDER  BY something?  -- add these lines ..
-- LIMIT  1;            -- .. if you want just one row
```

Be sure to have an **index on table_a (date_1, integer_2)** if performance matters.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, i need this: 
COLUMNS: A(INT),B(INT),C(DATE),D(DATE),E(INT), i need: all rows equal A,B,C where MAX(D) if more than one row with same A,B,C,D i need filter with MAX(E) but Need all reg with same A,B,C,D,E ... The biggest problem is that E sometimes is not correct seq for this i dont include in the firts filter.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT a.INTEGER_0, a.INTEGER_1, a.DATE_0, a.DATE_1, MAX(a.INTEGER_2) AS MaxInt2
FROM TABLE_A a           
INNER JOIN               
   (SELECT b.INTEGER_0, b.INTEGER_1, b.DATE_0, max(b.DATE_1) AS max_date
    FROM TABLE_A b     
    GROUP BY b.INTEGER_0, b.INTEGER_1, b.DATE_0
   ) AS result         
ON  a.INTEGER_0 = b.INTEGER_0
AND a.INTEGER_1 = b.INTEGER_1
AND a.DATE_0 = b.DATE_0  
AND a.DATE_1 = b.max_date
GROUP BY a.INTEGER_0, a.INTEGER_1, a.DATE_0, a.DATE_1
HAVING MAX(a.INTEGER_2) = 42 /* Adjust this according to what your filter needs */
```

Comment: Thank for your answer, but i need filter the result with the max INTEGER_2 in the rows that same INTEGER_0, INTEGER_1, DATE_0, DATE_1

Answer (score 0):

You have not specified which version of PostgreSQL you are using. If it's 8.4+, you could try a different approach and use a [ranking function](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/functions-window.html) for achieving your goal:

```
WITH ranked AS (
  SELECT
    INTEGER_0,
    INTEGER_1,
    DATE_0,
    DATE_1,
    INTEGER_2,
    RANK() OVER (
      PARTITION BY
        INTEGER_0,
        INTEGER_1,
        DATE_0
      ORDER BY
        DATE_1 DESC
    ) AS rnk
  FROM TABLE_A
)
SELECT
  INTEGER_0,
  INTEGER_1,
  DATE_0,
  DATE_1,
  INTEGER_2
FROM TABLE_A
WHERE rnk = 1
ORDER BY INTEGER_2 DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SET search_path='tmp';
-- generate some data
DROP TABLE atable CASCADE;
CREATE TABLE atable
    ( integer_0 INTEGER
    , integer_1 INTEGER
    , date_0 DATE
    , date_1 DATE
    , integer_2 INTEGER
    );  
INSERT INTO atable( integer_0,integer_1,date_0,date_1,integer_2)
VALUES
(1,7,'2011-02-01','2011-01-01',8)
,(1,7,'2011-02-01','2011-01-02',7)
,(1,7,'2011-02-01','2011-01-04',6)
,(1,7,'2011-02-01','2011-01-04',3)
,(1,7,'2011-02-01','2011-01-04',3)
    ;

-- Query the data
SELECT integer_0,integer_1,date_0,date_1,integer_2
FROM atable a0
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
    FROM atable a1
    WHERE a1.integer_0 = a0.integer_0
    AND a1.integer_1 = a0.integer_1
    AND a1.date_0 = a0.date_0
    AND a1.date_1 > a0.date_1
    )   
AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
    FROM atable a2
    WHERE a2.integer_0 = a0.integer_0
    AND a2.integer_1 = a0.integer_1
    AND a2.date_0 = a0.date_0
    AND a2.date_1 = a0.date_1
    AND a2.integer_2 > a0.integer_2
    )   
    ;
```